# WP8 SDK - What is new?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am away and as such, don't have any access to a PC with Visual Studio but I'm dying to know about the new WP8 SDK. In particular 2 aspects.

Now the WP7 SDK was quite limited (check out the forums of complaints) and I was wondering if any one can answer two questions as I am to impatient to wait until I'm back.

1. Does the SDK give me control of the phones volume?
   a. I wanted to make an app which turned the phone to silent based upon time of day and my outlook calender status (eg, don't ring if I'm in a meeting). This wasn't possible with WP7
2. Can I send text messages without user control (eg, as a background task).
   a. On WP7 you could schedule the message but the user had to still click the send button.

Or, does any one know of a 'what's new in WP8 SDK' they can point me too? Currently I can find nothing on Google (if such a thing exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the SDK give me control of the phones volume?

No

> I wanted to make an app which turned the phone to silent based upon time of day and my outlook calender status (eg, don't ring if I'm in a meeting). This wasn't possible with WP7

Still not possible.

> Can I send text messages without user control (eg, as a background task). a. On WP7 you could schedule the message but the user had to still click the send button.

No, you can't. The user still have to approve sending the message. Windows Phone is trying to avoid the security flaws of Android.

Comment: Well, that sucks but thank you for answering all my questions. I wonder if I should bite the bullet, learn Java and go Android :)  Thank you again

Comment: I'm sure the Android community would love yet another piece of malware to add to the list :P

Comment: ha ha, it would be for me only :) Honestly, having a text saying happy birthday has stopped my wife complaining that I missed it again too many times :) With WP7, I missed it!

Comment: you can have the user use Voice Commands, so they don't have to click the send button. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj721592.aspx

Comment: What about getting the volume level of the system on WP8? Is that possible? I just wish to show an indication about it, especially if it's in the lowest level (muted).

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a short 100+ pages article describing what's new in the WP8 SDK.

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8

Comment: That is THE most awesome article I have ever read. Real stuff which you usually see only in books, thanks Justin!

Comment: Pretty decent, but the image sizes for the TemplateIconic is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

What's new in Windows Phone SDK 8.0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

But maybe the new API reference helps a bit more. Since I think it's a bit hidden, here the direct link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626516%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: This is really good (and sad)! The library for .NET is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx (which I would not have found without your help) but it does not look like I will have access to the phones volume. Thank you.